# Indexing for data copy on production servers

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

We have a postgresql database that is used in production and a mysql database for reporting, that copies data from the production server. Now, my issue is that the reporting database is denormalized so it is not a simple replica of the production DB schema. The data from production is copied onto the reporting server using complex queries that transform the data into a desired format. My question is about any guidelines that are industry standards for a practice like this.  I would like to create indexes on the production server designed to make the complex queries for copying to reporting database faster. However, I would like to have some kind of quantifiable methods of measuring the pros and cons of creating these kind of indexes in the production server w.r.t its effect on the insert/update performance on the database. If anybody can provide some inputs based on experience or point me in the direction of some write-ups on this I would be grateful. I have tried google but haven't found anything that addresses an issue of this kind. 
Any input would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want help, it's best to include some code, otherwise this is far too broad of a question

Comment: I'm not looking for help with code though, just guidelines to this kind of practice. Is it even ok to write complex queries  directly from source, or should i be creating a separate staging database and create my indexes there? I'm trying to find out what other people do in situations like this, because I think plenty of organizations have separate reporting and production databases. Are there best practices in how one would go about doing this?

Comment: nomistic's question stands.  Is this a "Data Warehouse" application wherein "Summary Tables" are the standard (together with denormalization, complex queries, etc)?  Or is it something else?  There are no "industry standards", just good techniques.  But those techniques depend heavily on the situation.